# Notify ObservableCollection when property changes

Tags: c#, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I have the following classes.

```
Class Contract
{
   public double Bid { get; set; }
   ...
}

Class Leg
{
   public Contract con {get; set; }
   ...
}

class Combo
{
   public Leg L1 { get; set;}
   public Leg L2 { get; set;}
   ....
}

ObservableCollection<Combo> listOfCombos = new ObservableCollection<Combo>();
Combo cmbo = new Combo();
listOfCombos.Add(cmbo);

//datagrid bound to ObservableCollection
<DataGrid x:Name="dgCombos" ItemsSource="{Binding listOfCombos,Mode=OneWay}"
```

How do I notify the listOfCombos when a Bid property of a Contract changes. I also want the change to propagate to the datagrid.
I know how to notify ObservableCollection when a property of T (the only class) changes.
Im confused on how to notify, when theres more than one Class. ie. Combo > Leg > Contract. - Thanks

Comment: the class you want to notify needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and the setter of f.e. Bid should Raise this notification

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Xeun How do i raise the notification even in the Bid ? Combo.OnPropertyChange() is not recognized.

Comment: @AlgoAlpha see the link Lepijohny posted